# How to render ImGUI Texture on Android SurfaceView

Tags: android, c++, surfaceview, imgui

Currently, I' developing an android application which needs to render an ImGUI Texture (Native C++) on an android SurfaceView.

I have read about SDL Activity, however this approach doesnt fit my constrain (need to render on a View not Activity).

Are there any possible solution? Thanks in advance.